# How to delete openwrt ssl cert

Tags: ssl, openwrt, lede

I enabled HTTPS on openwrt by following the [howto](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/secure.access) some while ago.

Now I get a certificate warning in Firefox because it has expired.  How do I delete the old cert?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a shell on the openwrt box and run the following commands:

```
$ cd /etc
$ rm uhttpd.crt uhttpd.key
$ /etc/init.d/uhttpd restart
```

---

Found by viewing the uhttpd command line:

```
cat /proc/$(pgrep uhttpd)/cmdline | tr '\0' ' ' && echo
```

Result:

> /usr/sbin/uhttpd -f -h /www -r mortar.carrier.duckdns.org -x /cgi-bin -u /ubus -t 60 -T 30 -k 20 -A 1 -n 3 -N 100 -R -C /etc/uhttpd.crt -K /etc/uhttpd.key -s 0.0.0.0:443 -s [::]:443